# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

i am currently facing the issue below. the problem started occurring when i deleted my iOS folder and created a new one. ive set all the necessary settings back in place but am still facing the issue. i deleted the iOS file and recreated it as my 'project.pbxproj' file became empty. tia

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.
```

Comment: *firebaser here* We've heard from multiple developers in Singapore that they're having problems connecting to Cloud Storage through Firebase, so if you're getting this problem from that region it may be the same. I provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075451/firebase-storage-only-showing-when-on-certain-vpn) and will update that as we learn more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem in `firebase_storage`. Please use `putData` instead of `putFile`, that can work.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9480