# Firebase Storage Only showing when on certain VPN

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

i have my Firebase Storage 'located' at nam5, i reside in Singapore. My flutter project was working well up until yesterday. I started receiving this error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.
```

i also realised that the imageUrl provided from firebase storage was no longer accessible for me. then, i decided to use a vpn and voila, it works. my question is, is there a restriction to firebase storage in terms of location access? do i have to set up a new project in order to change the region? or is some of my settings wrong? i apologise if i am not describing the problem well enough. am very new to flutter, firebase, etc.

Answer (score 5):

*firebaser here*

We've seen multiple reports from users in Singapore being unable to access data in Cloud Storage through Firebase. We tracked the status of this issue [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/gAJbQsuZv3kiuNbjQHvP), and it has now been closed.

---

**Update**: We're working to get a status banner up on https://status.cloud.google.com/. I'll update here once that exists, as that may be a more direct way to track status.

---

**Update**: This is now reported as a service health issue on https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/gAJbQsuZv3kiuNbjQHvP. I recommend checking there for the latest status.

---

**Update**: The Cloud Storage for Firebase connectivity issue has been resolved for all affected users as of Saturday, 2022-07-23 00:10 US/Pacific.

Comment: thank you so much! could you please also indicate when it started happening?

Comment: Since this happens to the requests before they ever reach our infrastructure, we don't have that information at the moment.

Comment: Is this issue happening again? I am seeing similar issues as of yesterday and also today. I do not see any issues on status.cloud.google.com though.

Comment: I've seen some reports of a Singapore telco network having traffic issues since yesterday indeed, but you'll want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.