# STORAGE EMULATOR ISSUE: Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm trying to upload an image to storage emulator locally from iOS simulator (the same thing works without issues on Android):
This is the error:

```
WARNING: Unable to set the Firebase Storage emulator settings. These must be set before any usages of Firebase Storage. If you see this log after a hot reload/restart you can safely ignore it.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response
```

It isn't much to work with.. I searched everywhere and found no working solutions. There seems to be similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075451/firebase-storage-only-showing-when-on-certain-vpn) that was related to connecting to production storage.
But this still doesn't work for me on local emulator.

Comment: Try with uninstalling some app, and run again

Comment: I tried that. Still same issue persists.

Comment: Verified that everything works when I push images to prod firestore. Only local emulator is having issues..

Comment: When I run pod update I get firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'. I hope this is right version to be used.

Comment: Does it work on a physical iOS device?